# axios/ fetch failed but postman work with php api

Tags: php, reactjs, axios, fetch

I got stuck when calling php api with `form-data` type in my React app. When I test with Postman, it works correctly but failed in react.

Please let me know if I'm doing wrong here.
In Postman, call api like this:

```
URl_API: xxxx/yyyy.php.
Config in Body tab in key/value: form-data
k: "some string"
id: "some string"
```

With axios, I had an error:

My code:

```js
const formData = new FormData()
  formData.append('k', 'some string')
  formData.append('id', 'some string')

  const response = await axios.post('xxxx/yyyy.php', formData, {
    headers: {
      'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*',
    },
  })
```

```
xxxx/yyyy.php net::ERR_HTTP2_PROTOCOL_ERROR
```

I had already tried with fetch but no luck - call api success with status 200 but the `response.text()` is empty.
With fetch api:

```js
const result = await fetch('xxxx/yyyy.php', {
    method: 'POST',
    mode: 'no-cors',
    body: formData,
    cache: 'no-cache',
  })
    .then(async (res) => {
      return res.text()
    })
    .then((text) => console.log('It is empty here', text))
```

Comment: Apparently Axios [still doesn't support HTTP2](https://github.com/axios/axios/issues/1175). As for the problem with `fetch`, what type of response is expected?

Comment: What error are you getting in your browser's console as it stands your not providing us with the information we need, per https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask please provide the error from the browser's console, if on safari you have to enable developer options,  other browser press F12 and go to the console tab. read the errors. and provide us the relevant one for each of the methods you have used please.

Answer (score 1):

It look like a CORS also, but you will be able to sort it out

a simple solution in development is to use a local api server, and finally when the app is deployed to the server which is on the same domain as the api, you should get the response, as demonstrated below by making the calls using dev tools.

in short: if a api calls work with postman but not through the browser, its mostly due to cors restrictions, then it could be the response type

Verifying cors issue by making calls throught dev tools

```
 let onSubmit = async () => {
    try {
      const url = "https://www.your-domain***.com/getUrlApp.php";

      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append("k", "kk");
      formData.append("id", "dd");
      const data = new URLSearchParams(formData);

      const response = await fetch(url, {
        method: "POST", // *GET, POST, PUT, DELETE, etc.
        mode: "no-cors", // no-cors, *cors, same-origin
        body: data // body data type must match "Content-Type" header
      });

      //const res = response.json();
      const buffer = await response.arrayBuffer();

      const decoder = new TextDecoder("iso-8859-1");
      const text = decoder.decode(buffer);

      console.log("text", text);

      return response;
    } catch (error) {
      console.log("error", error);
    }
  };
```

To verify the response

- go https://www.your-domain***.com
- open dev tools => console
- past the function above and run it by typing onSubmit() in the console

you will see the response

Hope it helps you in some way

[image]

Comment: Many thanks. It works on chrome dev tools, but still no response in my react code. I copied exact the same code you post above here. And another question, how can you know the textDecoder?

Comment: The response header contains content-type →text/html;charset=UTF-8, so to get json  resonse, you need to send json from the server and handle the cors issue atlest in dev mode, since the app will be able to make the get the response when deployed on the same domain as the api, in production
if it helps you consider upvoting, 
Cheers

Comment: Maybe it has some issues in api that filtered the response when I call from react. Please help me to remove the `k`, `id` and `url` in your answer.

Comment: Done, the k and id is removed, try to handle the cors and json response from the api side,  things will work, 
nor try to setup a local api, with that response, or may be a mock server, cuz during the production if the app is on same domain the api calls will work